# How do I rename columns of a df with a for loop and new column names deriving from other df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I made a dataframe from a bigger dataframe with a for loop and and the group by function. The multiindexed dataframe has the name 'Area' for all columns and the second level for all columns is called 'mean'. I am indexing the columns by iloc and wanted to give them names based on a different dataframe.

Could you help me out? If you have a completely different approach I am thankful too, of course.

```
bis=len(index_df['amount'])
for c, d in zip (index_df['amount'], (bis)): 
    num[c] = num.iloc[:,[d]]
```

I get the following error message:
'TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration'

Comment: What do you want to happen when you `zip` over a *number* like `bis`?

Comment: bis is 4 and the dataframe has 4 columns. I wanted to index every single column and rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over an integer, but you can iterate over a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) object, e.g. `range(len(index_df.index))`. But, in any case, `=` in Pandas is used for assignment, not for renaming, unless you combine it with [`pd.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html).

If each column of `num` relates to a value in `index_df['amount']`, and the relation is aligned by integer position, you can simply use assignment:

```
num.columns = index_df['amount']
```

And that's it, no manual iteration involved.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot. That again underlines that I am coding on a very low level. Haha But still, how would it work with iterations? I didn't use range because (to my knowledge) I cannot iterate over two columns...